# map.setView получение LatLng через Json

Tags: javascript, json, leafletjs, 2gis-api

Доброе время суток, задача стоит следующая, необходимо менять центр карты 2GIS при клике по кнопке
для этого есть функция map.setView(), она прекрасно работает если есть координаты, например

```
map.setView([48.4593767, 35.0233062], 17);
```

Проблема в том что координаты я получаю через AJAX (Json) и в таком случае ничего не работает

```
map.setView([json.geocode], 17);
```

Лог показывает следующее (в первом случае):

```
(2) [48.4593767, 35.0233062] 17
```

Во втором случае

```
["48.4593767, 35.0233062"] 17
```

Проблема заключается в том что не распознаются координаты, так как есть двойные кавычки, как их убрать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```js
map.setView(json.geocode.split(', ').map(Number.parseFloat), 17);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает так, а это не сильно большой костыль ?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, два числа с координатами передаются в JSON как одна строка. Пожалуй, это самый прямой способ превратить эту строку в массив с двумя числами, который требуется сигнатурой функции.